# The project target(Android 2.1) was not properly loaded

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, target

I recently re-installed all my SDKs and I'm getting errors which i am trying to work with newly created Android Projects in Eclipse.

When I try to create a new Android Project in Eclipse, the project appears that has created successfully, however R.java is not being generated properly.

I am getting the error message **The project target (Android 2.1) was not properly loaded.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just restart your Eclipse  then go your project **Properties-->Android-->Project Build Target** change the API level and view XML file.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Project and hit Clean. This should, among others, regenerate your R.java file.

Also get rid of any import android.R.* statements and then do the clean up I mentioned.

Apparently Jonas problem was related to incorrect target build settings. His target build was set to Android 2.1 (SDK v7) where his layout XML used Android 2.2 (SDK v8) elements (layout parameter match_parent), due to this there was no way for Eclipse to correctly generate the R.java file which caused all the problems.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that your SDK path is correct and that the 2.1 Build Target is selected?

1. Check SDK Path by selecting `Window --> Preferences --> Android`
2. Check Build Target by the following: Select your project name in the "Project Explorer" view and hit Alt+Enter